# Adding custom domain to Site.com but how to make CNAME enhanced domain compatible?

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com, custom-domain, enhanced-domains

If an org is yet to enable enhanced domains and a custom domain needs to be added to a site (site.com), the [current documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.siteforce_domains.htm&type=5) says to create a CNAME like so:

> ... if your domain name is [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com) and your organization ID is 00dx00000000001aaa, then the CNAME must be [www.mycompany.com.00dx00000000001aaa.live.siteforce.com](http://www.mycompany.com.00dx00000000001aaa.live.siteforce.com).

However, it is not clear if this URL format is still valid once enhanced domains is enabled. Looking through [all the URL changes affected by enhanced domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_url_format_changes_enable_enhanced.htm&type=5), there's no mention of a `live.siteforce.com` host/domain.

So will anything need to change on the CNAME once enhanced domains is enabled?

Is the answer the same if adding a custom domain / CNAME to production and sandboxes?

Thank you.

Comment: Covered in FAQ: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393816&type=1

Comment: Thanks @identigral if you post this an an answer, I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

[According to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393816&type=1#cname), the URL will not change:

> Enhanced domains don't change the live.siteforce.com hostnames. Custom domains using live.siteforce.com continue to function as before when you enable enhanced domains.